# Custom open graph stories being changed

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've created custom open graph sentences for my story.

There is an open-graph action called **Send** and an open-graph object called **Treat**.
The story is called `Send a Treat`.

This issue is that after a day or so, the custom sentences are reverted to their previous values!

For example, for `One to One`:

I changed it to `Simon has sent a treat`.
However after a day when we started testing it, it changes back to `Simon has sent {treat.title}`

Is it because our custom sentences contain the word 'treat'? Has anyone else had this problem? Is there a way around it?

**Update**
Response from Facebook bug report:
This is by design. If you want to trigger the "One to One - Without Object Title" story, you need to leave the og:title tag empty. More info:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/#objects-without-titles

*What?*
Every time I change a sentence in the OpenGraph->Stories section, it just reverts back to its previous value.  This can't be 'by design'...

Comment: have you figured it out yet?

Comment: no i haven't. stopped working on the project but i'll try asking the people still working on it.